# Not seeing script output in Jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, git-bash

I am calling a script from Jenkins pipeline like so:

```
stage('Prepare Windows') {  
  steps {
    bat '''echo prepare steps on windows'''
    bat '''E:\\compass\\preparation\\windows\\prepare_sources.sh juice E:\\builds\\mapps_builds 0.6.0'''
  }
}
```

It works nicely, but the echo statements executed inside the script do not appear in the Jenkins console e.g

```
echo "=================================="
echo " Preparing build ${BUILD_NUMBER}"
echo "=================================="
```

I tried:

```
bat '''E:\\compass\\preparation\\windows\\prepare_sources.sh juice E:\\builds\\mapps_builds 0.6.0 2>&1'''
```

I have also tried based on the feedback below:

```
script {
  def prepareWindowsStdout = bat(label: 'Prepare Windows Sources', script: "E:\\compass\\preparation\\windows\\prepare_sources.sh juice E:\\builds\\mapps_builds ${env.TRACK}", returnStdout: true)
  print prepareWindowsStdout
}
```

It compiles and runs, but does not print out any output from the bash script.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Thanks